# How and when do Mercurial or git diff files?

Tags: git, mercurial, synchronization

I am on a project about file sync. I have some questions:

- Who can tell me how Mercurial or Git diff files and store the diffs?
- Does it monitor file change?
- Does it need to diff the whole file when making a commit?
- Whether it can monitor the change of section by driver?
- What's the differences between the way of processing text files and binary files?
- Is there any other opensource software that I should to research?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen  I am new to this area of work,also a newer of python， and I am reading the code,but I can't find my answer as quickly as I need，maybe my way of research is too poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mercurial, it differs between *showing* a diff, and *storing* the diff.

When *showing* the diff, it depends on whether you ask Mercurial itself to show the diff, or if you ask it to use an external diff program.

Here are all the combinations:

1. Storing the diff

   1. Always uses binary diff, does not matter what kind of file it is (or is assumed to be)
2. Showing the diff

   1. Asking Mercurial to show the diff

      1. Will complain if it is a binary file (that is, that Mercurial *assumes* it is a binary file)
      2. Will show the diff if it is a text file (again, assumed)
   2. Asking external program to show the diff

      1. Depends on what that external program is able to handle

As for monitoring the changes, Mercurial does not do this. When you ask it to commit, at that point it figures out which files to store and what changes to commit for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you said Mercurial Always uses binary diff,but I always find code for "line" and "text",not binary,what's the algorithm used？